# Ошибка при создании миграций

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Я использую Django 2.2.10 , python3.7

Без поля many to many все работает

mainpage/models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Task(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    executor = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='id', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Задача'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Задачи'


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

при попытке python manage.py makemigrations mainpage

выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/checks.py", line 74, in check_user_model
    if isinstance(cls().is_anonymous, MethodType):
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 486, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.attname, val)
  File "/home/ian/Passion/django_girls/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 538, in __set__
    % self._get_set_deprecation_msg_params(),
TypeError: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use id.set() instead.
```

Хочется узнать, что я делаю не так при создании отношения ManyToMany? И как это сделать правильно?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015204/direct-assignment-to-the-forward-side-of-a-many-to-many-set-is-prohibited-use-e

Comment: Я похоже понял, я убрал related_name='id'. И при попытке сделать миграции вышли другие ошибки

Comment: Ok 13 символов нужно...

Comment: `ERRORS:
mainpage.Task.author: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Task.author' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Task.executor'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Task.author' or 'Task.executor'.
mainpage.Task.executor: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Task.executor' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Task.author'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Task.executor' or 'Task.author'.
WARNINGS:
mainpage.Task.executor: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.`

Comment: Тогда задайте лучше отдельный вопрос

Comment: У вас тут `related_name` явно неправильный, потому что `id` пересекается с уже существующим полем в модели User. Попробуйте что-то вроде `related_name='authored_tasks'` и `related_name='executed_tasks'` соответственно, вдруг поможет

Comment: related_name - это поле в модели User значение которого я подставляю в поле executor?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо написать так

```
executor = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)
```