# Ошибка при создании миграции в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Django=2.2.10, python3.7

mainpage/models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Task(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    executor = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Задача'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Задачи'


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

При попытке python manage.py makemigrations mainpage

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
mainpage.Task.author: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Task.author' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Task.executor'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Task.author' or 'Task.executor'.
mainpage.Task.executor: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Task.executor' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Task.author'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Task.executor' or 'Task.author'.

WARNINGS:
mainpage.Task.executor: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
```

Что в данном случае делать? Как я понимаю, нужно указать, чтобы значение в поле executor не было равно значению в поле author - верно-ли мое предположение?

Comment: В тексте ошибки английским по белому написано что делать — «Add or change a related_name argument»

Comment: Если связь в обратную сторону не требуется, то можно прописать `related_name='+'`

Comment: Я пытался добавить related_name
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108428/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, объяснить связь в обратную сторону?

Comment: Можно этого добиться указанием в поле many to many symmetrical=False?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том , что у автора вопроса был конфликт из-за `related_name`.

В модели `Task` поля `author` и `executor` - связи с одной и той же моделью. По умолчанию `related_name` генерится из названия модели. Так как `django` не может разрулить, как найти объекты связанные по `executor` и по `author`, просит добавить `related_name`.

Решение - указать `related_name="tasks_as_author"` и `related_name="tast_as_executor"` для соотвествующих полей, либо `related_name="+"`, что уберет возможность обращения из `User`

Пример

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="tasks_as_author",
    )
    executor = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, 
        blank=True, 
        null=True,
        related_name="tasks_as_executor",
    )
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема. Решение: нужно убрать null=True

Comment: ответ от автора вопроса, вроде бы, о том же самом.

Answer (score -1):

Я решил эту проблему немного по другому, модель Profile связана OneToOne с моделью User. Я написал код так

```
executor = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True)
```

И выводилась ошибка, что Profile не импортирован
И потом я поменял Profile на User и ошибок стало еще больше
Нужно было сделать

```
executor = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', blank=True)
```

Comment: Решение не подходит

Comment: @ZaArs можете описать в чем проблема?

Comment: описал ответом.